# I always get "[400] Invalid Value" whenever I filter on something using Exits.results()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics-api, garb-gem

I can't figure out what I'm always getting 400. This is my model:

```
class G2
   extend Garb::Model
   metrics :pageviews
end
```

and this is my call:

```
G2.results(profile, :filters => {:pageviews.gte=>3})
```

and I get this:

```
Garb::BadRequestError: [400] Invalid Value : https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:XXXXXXXX&start-date=2013-01-07&end-date=2013-02-06&metrics=ga:pageviews&filters=ga:pageviews%3E%3D3
```

If I don't include the `:filters` symbol, then the request will be successful. I tested this query using the GA Query Tool and it works.

Any thing I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a bug caused by a recent check-in to garb. The author (sija) has reverted the change and this issue no longer reproduces: https://github.com/Sija/garb/issues/17